# Cleaning date column in python with multiple date formats

Tags: python

I am cleaning up a dataframe that has date of birth and date of death as a string. There are multiple formats of dates in those columns. Some contain just year (which is all I need). These are the formats of dates:

```
Jan 10 2020
1913 
10/8/2019
June 14th 1980
```

All I need is the year from each date. I have not been having any luck with pandas to_datetime since a significant portion of the rows only have year to begin with.

Is there a way for me to pull just year from the strings so that I can get each column to look like:

```
2020
1913
2019
1980
```

Comment: You could hit it with some regex that matches any 4 digit string that starts with 1 or 2. Like `[12][0-9]{3}`. Likely this ends up being death-from-one-thousand-edge-cases, but that seems like a good first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to use a parser which will accept these and other formats:

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser 

df  = pd.DataFrame({"mydates":["Jan 10 2020", "1913", "10/8/2019", "June 14th 1980"]})
df['years'] = df['mydates'].apply(parser.parse).dt.strftime('%Y')
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.extract`:

```
df['BirthDate'] = df['BirthDate'].str.extract(r'\d{4}')
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for the dates that had more than just year -- it looks like when the row only had a year however it changed the value to NAN